# cpu is overheating when working on linux mint

Tags: cpu, temperature

I don't think that I'm doing anything could affect my CPU temperature but it's shown that the temperature is high and my laptop is actually overheating, and is lagging when I'm working on Linux Mint. However, when I'm working on Windows in browsing mode, just like what I'm doing on Linux Mint, my laptop CPU temperature is always fine. The temperature only increases if I'm playing games or something similar that could increase the temperature.

[image: temperature readings from bpytop]

[image: my laptop details]

Comment: are you using fractional display scaling? That could cause heavy CPU use.

Answer (score 0):

I advise to check intel GPU load (with `intel_gpu_top`). Desktop compositor can be the case because it usually uses iGPU.